# Restoring TextBox Values after PostBack

Tags: asp.net

In form_Load I get existing data from the database like this:

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        getDatabaseDataAndFillOutTextControls()
    End if
```

After all the asp:textbox controls are filled the user then enters/changes values in the textbox controls and clicks an asp:imagebutton to save the data. The problem is after the postback, the values for the textbox controls are all set to the values as they came from the database, and I have confirmed that no additional call to the db has been made.

I already found that AutoEventWireup was set to "false" but setting it to "true" did not alter the behavior. The only thing I can think of is this is an older ASP.NET application that I ported, which uses a lot of JavaScript, for what appears to be mainly validation.

Anybody ever come across this?

Comment: so the issue here is you want to reload user input after postback. Why are you loading from DB? Should you save data back to DB on postback/submit? Then you get back the data from DB?

Comment: @lucidgold Yes, I am trying to save the data back to the database (not shown) but the text fields have the original values, and not the values changed in the form.

Comment: Then you must save the data after the user submits. Is there a button that processess the data and does update/insert to DB?

Comment: There sure is, but when I get say the value for "textBox1.Text", the value is the original value not any new value typed in. I have tried using ViewState but that does not work either. EanbleViewState is "true" for the form and the controls.

Comment: You need to provide some code. Are you saying there is a control that produces postback and after the postback the user loses all entered data and old data is re-loaded from DB?

Comment: That is exactly as you said it. I'm just going to painstakingly rebuild this application. It was ported quickly and I think some legacy setting is causing the unusual behavior. thanks

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to see if IsPostBack was set to TRUE on the postback?

Comment: @Gridly Yes I did and it was. Thanks.